Can attaching magnets to a radiator cause issues?
My house uses large 3 panel low temperature radiators (Purmo C33). I'm planning on attaching some computer fans on the bottom to force air through some radiators to increase the airflow to have even better efficiency. The mounting system I envisioned uses magnets.
Could the magnets attract cause magnetic particles inside the system to get stuck and cause blockages?

scoot the magnets a unit to the side every year to release the particles.

It depends on the magnets if strong enough the could cause rust particles to accumulate but cast iron will block most of the magnetic field, so the magnets will need to be strong to cause this.
If you can arrange you magnets in a Halbach array that will increase the holding power of the magnets and reduce the penetration of the magnetic fields.
2x20 magnets are fairly strong, but most of the field will be blocked by the cast iron radiator, if you switch to 2x10 or 2x5 magnets in a checkerboard up-down pattern  the cast iron will block the magnetic field even better.

I'm using 4x 20x2mm neodymium magnets per fan, which seem to just barely hold the 3D printed mount with the fan on the radiator.

Umm, I don't think rust is that atteacted to a magnet

"Halbach array" I learned something new today!

I had to Google it.....now I'm smarter than I was yesterday.

Rust is not that attracted to a magnetic field. So it doesnt matter what you do.

Red rust, hematite (Fe2O3) is not magnetic. Black rust, magnetite, (Fe3O4), is magnetic as its name suggests. Black rust is the species that normally forms in a sealed heating system due to its low oxygen content. Still, an external magnetic field will barely penetrate cast iron and no clog will occur even if the black rust coating on the inside wall of the radiator in the vicinity of the magnet becomes a few nm thicker.
